# how to write multiple condition along with 301 redirect in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In my website i want to make 301 redirection rule and vanity url using .htaccess file and my code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^availany.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.availany.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

and in web page it shows 500internal error,in which position i done mistake do suggest me

Comment: What is your last rule doing and why do you have `</pre>` there?

Comment: @anubhava last four line is when a user type url ie.     your-url.com/philipbrown and routes it to profile.php?user=philipbrown. acc.to dis blog http://culttt.com/2011/11/16/how-to-make-vanity-urls-using-php-htaccess-and-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^availany\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```